# Display colours look dry and less vibrant with default applications.

Tags: display, color-management

My display looks very drab and less vibrant when images are viewed with the default applications (Image Viewer, in this case). And even in Chrome (which is also my default browser), the colours look very dry. I don't remember any change that I could have probably made in my colour settings.

Here are three screenshots. One viewed with Image Viewer, and the other one, which is much more vibrant, viewed with Pix. The third screenshot shows my current colour settings. I use Linux Mint 18.2.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From `Menu > Preference > Colour`, does changing the color profile affect images viewed in Image Viewer?

You might try posting the results of `sudo inxi -Fxzd` to give us more details about your environment.

I also recommend checking if you have a Xorg config set at `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`.

If so, check and make sure `Gamma` setting isn't configured.

Though, I doubt this will help since Pix is showing them fine...